# How to add a toggle input button in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

On one of my models, I want to use a toggle button instead of a radio button in the Active Admin form.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show whatever you have tried so far. It will be better if you can add here the code or solutions you have tried.

Comment: for e.g I have used f.input :has_color which automatically enable radio button field in active admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#boolean-values useful. Check out the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/) for other resources.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pure css to make radio buttons appear as switches. Search this [link](https://codepen.io/) if you want to find other options.

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/wiljanslofstra/pen/xqOKZW) to the code I found in `codepen.io`

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0
}

.toggle input:nth-child(2):checked {
  z-index: 1;
}

.toggle__pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 0;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #37b24d;
  -webkit-transition: left .15s ease-out;
  transition: left .15s ease-out;
}

.toggle input:nth-child(2):checked+.toggle__pointer {
  left: 22px;
  background-color: #495057;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <input type="radio" value="on" name="radio">
  <input type="radio" value="off" name="radio" checked>
  <div class="toggle__pointer"></div>
</div>
```